# Watch for changes in DOM elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hy there, I have a form with 4 `<input type='text'>` and a disabled `<button>`.

2 of those `<input type='text>`are readonly and will automatically filled when the other is being given values triggered by keyup() event.

My question, how can I remove `<button>`'s attribute that is "disabled" when that two "disabled" `<input type='text'>` have been given values? where do I have to put events?

Here's my code :

```
<input type="text" class="firstbox" name='firstbox' required>
<input type="text" class='automaticfilling' readonly="readonly"
 placeholder='will be filled as input.firstbox is being typed'>

<input type="text" class="secondbox" name='secondbox' required>
<input type="text" class='automaticfillingtwo' readonly="readonly"
 placeholder='will be filled as input.secondbox is being typed'>

<button type='button' value='click me' disabled='disabled'>
```

JQuery Code :

```
$(function(){

$('input.firstbox').keyup(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
 $('input.automaticfilling').val(value);
});

$('input.secondbox').keyup(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
 $('input.automaticfillingtwo').val(value);
});

//In what element should I put an trigger for enabling button 
//after those two readonly textboxes has been filled?

});
```

Comment: You want to observe the change event of the hidden boxes, and when it is fired check that both boxes are filled, if so then remove the disabled attribute from your button, otherwise add it. To do this you could use attr() or prop()

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check the state of the `readonly` `input` elements after you set their values. If both of them have a value, you can remove the `disabled` property from the `button`. Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var $auto1 = $('input.automaticfilling'), 
        $auto2 = $('input.automaticfillingtwo');

    $('input.firstbox').keyup(function(){
        $auto1.val($(this).val());
        checkAutoValues();
    });

    $('input.secondbox').keyup(function(){
        $auto2.val($(this).val());
        checkAutoValues();
    });

    function checkAutoValues() {
        $('button').prop('disabled', !($auto1.val() && $auto2.val()));
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7bydv28/)

Note that the button will be enabled when both boxes have values, and disabled when either one of them has no value.

Also note that you can make the JS code completely agnostic of the number of `autofilling` boxes you have by using DOM traversal to find the required elements. Try this:

```
<div class="auto-container">
    <input type="text" class="firstbox" name='firstbox' required />
    <input type="text" class='automaticfilling' readonly="readonly" placeholder='will be filled as input.firstbox is being typed' />
</div>

<div class="auto-container">
    <input type="text" class="firstbox" name='firstbox' required />
    <input type="text" class='automaticfilling' readonly="readonly" placeholder='will be filled as input.firstbox is being typed' />
</div>

<button type='button' value='click me' disabled='disabled'>Click me</button>
```

```js
$('input.firstbox').keyup(function () {
    $(this).closest('.auto-container').find('.automaticfilling').val($(this).val());

    var buttonEnabled = true;
    $('.automaticfilling').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            buttonEnabled = false;
            return;
        }
    });
    $('button').prop('disabled', !buttonEnabled);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7bydv28/1/)